# How to open *.htm differently than *.html?

Tags: gnome, html, mime-type, xdg

I'm trying to get `*.htm` files to open in a different application than for `*.html` (MIME Type `text/html`), as generally described in [GNOME Help > Add a custom MIME type for all users](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom.html.en).  I've created `/usr/share/mime/packages/htm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="application/x-html-notepad">
    <sub-class-of type="text/html"/>
    <comment>HTML Notepad</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.htm"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

and updated the desktop database as root (`update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`).  It still shows the built in HTML mime type for an HTML file with the `*.htm` extension, as if the above definition had no effect (removing the `<sub-class-of>` makes no difference):

```
$ gio info saved-web-page.htm | grep standard::content-type
  standard::content-type: text/html
```

Even when there's no HTML in the file it ignores the custom MIME type definition:

```
$ touch empty-file.htm
$ gio info empty-file.htm | grep standard::content-type
  standard::content-type: text/plain
```

Please, what have I missed?  I'm on GNOME 3.28.2 / Ubuntu 18.04.

***EDIT:*** I've since phrased the question more fundamentally here on a different forum: [MIME type text/html: how & where defined?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533552/mime-type-text-html-how-where-defined)

Comment: Could it be that "*.htm" is already defined in ``freedesktop.org.xml``, and your definition doesn't override that one?

Comment: It could be; I'd never heard of that file before. On my system `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml` is over 40K lines and definition `<mime-type type="text/html">` begins on line 33910. Is this file or format spec documented anywhere, or should I get reverse engineering? Or can a local copy of that definition (e.g. `~/.local/share/mime/packages/html+htm.xml`) override the global one in the MIME cache, with 2 separate definitions for each `<glob>` pattern?

Comment: So here's the best description of what's in that file (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/), which includes no practical information about how to alter the industry standard definitions on an individual system (the link at the top of my OP only addresses **new** MIME types). Hence the reverse engineering: instead, I'd like to know how, or whether, such an override would work before I start coding. Even a partial answer about overriding would be a valid answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As established in comments to the OP, the `text/html` MIME type is defined in `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`.  This can be overridden by a user by placing a new definition of `text/html` in the local MIME folder `~/.local/share/mime/packages`.

This MIME type may be applied to the two target file extensions because of these lines of XML in the file above:

```
  <mime-type type="text/html">
    ...
    <glob pattern="*.html"/>
    <glob pattern="*.htm"/>
  </mime-type>
```

So I've been able to split the two MIME types according to extension by creating a file `~/.local/share/mime/packages/html-split.xml` looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="text/html">
    <comment>HTML document</comment>
    ... INCLUDING EVERYTHING UP UNTIL <glob> FROM THE OLD DEFINITION ...
    <glob pattern="*.html"/>
  </mime-type>
  <mime-type type="application/x-html-notepad">
    <sub-class-of type="text/html"/>
    <comment>HTML Notepad</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.htm"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

What I've NOT tested: how pattern matches in the `<magic>` section remaining in the XML definition for `text/html` might prevent MIME type `application/x-html-notepad` from being applied to an `*.htm` file.  So comments about the `<magic>` tag, especially its `priority=` attribute, will be welcome here.